# Aggregation Support for Spring Data Elastic Search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Elastic search has deprecated Facets and recommend to use Aggregations (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations.html) .

Is Spring Data Elastic Search supports this currently ?

If Yes, is there any Samples available ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes aggregation is supported.

Example :

```
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAggregatedResponseForGivenSearchQuery() {
    // given
    IndexQuery article1 = new ArticleEntityBuilder("1").title("article four").subject("computing").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addAuthor(MOHSIN_HUSEN).addAuthor(JONATHAN_YAN).score(10).buildIndex();
    IndexQuery article2 = new ArticleEntityBuilder("2").title("article three").subject("computing").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addAuthor(MOHSIN_HUSEN).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(20).buildIndex();
    IndexQuery article3 = new ArticleEntityBuilder("3").title("article two").subject("computing").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2001).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(30).buildIndex();
    IndexQuery article4 = new ArticleEntityBuilder("4").title("article one").subject("accounting").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2002).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2001).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(40).buildIndex();

    elasticsearchTemplate.index(article1);
    elasticsearchTemplate.index(article2);
    elasticsearchTemplate.index(article3);
    elasticsearchTemplate.index(article4);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(ArticleEntity.class, true);

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .withSearchType(COUNT)
            .withIndices("articles").withTypes("article")
            .addAggregation(terms("subjects").field("subject"))
            .build();
    // when
    Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }
    });
    // then
    assertThat(aggregations, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(aggregations.asMap().get("subjects"), is(notNullValue()));
}
```

code is copied from [ElasticsearchTemplateAggregationTests.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/aggregation/ElasticsearchTemplateAggregationTests.java)

Comment: I have used the same but the part the extract aggregation part takes considerable amount of time, because of which my response time is getting increased

Answer (score 5):

To prevent a second call to elasticsearch you can extract the serachResult directly.

```
elasticsearchTemplate.query(query.build(), new ResultsExtractor<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object extract(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
            Aggregations aggregations = searchResponse.getAggregations();
            List<AnyClass> ta = new DefaultResultMapper().mapResults(searchResponse, AnyClass.class, new PageRequest(page != null ? page : 0, 15)).getContent();
            return ta;
        }
    });
```